# Why am I getting Segmentation fault while using isdigit function?

Tags: c, cs50

I run into segmentation fault while implementing the following program. Though, the code seems to work partially when I change the variable argv into char *argv, and make subsequent pointers.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[] ){

    if(argc == 1) {
        printf("Error");
    }
    else if (argc ==2 )
    {
        if(isdigit(argv[1]))
        {
        int key = atoi (argv[1]);
        printf("Success");

        }
    }
    else  {

       printf("Error");

    }

}
```

Comment: Since you've used the `cs50` tag, we can probably assume that `string` is `char *`, but your code does not show any includes, so it's not really certain.  It's best not to use non-standard types in questions.

Comment: `printf("Error");` is always questionable.  Errors belong on stderr.  `fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");` is preferred.

Comment: Note that the behavior of `atoi` is undefined on overflow/underflow.  You should probably (almost certainly, where "almost" is just being polite) use `strtol`.

Answer (score 0):

`isdigit()` expects a character argument, but you're passing a pointer.    You probably want to loop over all the characters in `argv[1]`, and make sure they're all digits before calling `atoi()`.